# Scrollview automatically extend height of linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with height of linear layout. When I use only linear layout, my form is scaled to screen size, and everything look like good. But now, I need to have scrollview only when I click an edittext and keyboard appear. I set scrollview as a root of my layout, but it extended height of this layout. Scrollview should be work only while keyboard appear, but now it work's every time and ruined my linearlayout. So right now, when I'm using a scrollview, layout is bigger than screen size. What should I do?

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.FormDialog"
>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:background="@drawable/new_background">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/applogo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"/>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >
            <TextView
                    android:text="Info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/missedCall"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" android:textSize="15sp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" android:weightSum="1">
            <ImageView
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:id="@+id/leftButton"
                    android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/left"/>
            <TextView
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:layout_width="244dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/numberTextView"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color" android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:id="@+id/rightButton"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
                android:text="Text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color" android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/missedCall" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:hint="Edit1" android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit2"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit3"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/companyEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Edit4"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/blueborder"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="20dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="3.33"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" android:hint="Edit5" android:lines="2" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="top|center_vertical"/>
        <CheckBox
                android:text="Check1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/newContactCheckbox"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <CheckBox
                android:text="Check2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/isWantedCheckbox" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
                android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <Button
                android:text="Send"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/addButton" android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textColor="#02485a" android:background="@drawable/blackborder"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/notRegisterTextView"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:padding="7dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And in Manifest I set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"

Comment: Try to change your ScrollView and LinearLayout height to wrap-content

Comment: It isn't a solution :(

Comment: And wrapping ScrollView inside RelativeLayout??

Comment: It's look like linearLayout is bigger than scrollview